# Draggable divs in jquery must be selected in order for positon to be stored to database

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a page where I can position divs using my mouse and then store the positon data in a database using php. I want to be able to move multiple divs at once and store their position.

My problem is with jquery. The code only allows me to select, move and store information of multiple divs when I select them in the order they appear in the code below. Moving them one and one works fine.

The jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $("#1").multidraggable();
                               $("#1").mousedown(function(){
                               pos1 = '1';
                               });

    $("#2").multidraggable();
                               $("#2").mousedown(function(){
                               pos2 = '2';
                               });

    $("#3").multidraggable();
                               $("#3").mousedown(function(){
                               pos3 = '3';
                               });

    $("#4").multidraggable();
                               $("#4").mousedown(function(){
                               pos4 = '4';
                               });

    $("#5").multidraggable();
                               $("#5").mousedown(function(){
                               pos5 = '5';
                               });

    $("#6").multidraggable();
                               $("#6").mousedown(function(){
                               pos6 = '6';
                               });

            $(".element").mouseup(function(){
                   var coord1 = $('#1').position();
                   var url1 = "updatecoords.php?x=" + coord1.left + "&y=" + coord1.top + "&id=" + pos1 + "";
                   $('#result1').load(url1, function() {
                   });
                   var coord2 = $('#2').position();
                   var url2 = "updatecoords.php?x=" + coord2.left + "&y=" + coord2.top + "&id=" + pos2 + "";
                   $('#result2').load(url2, function() {
                   });
                   var coord3 = $('#3').position();
                   var url3 = "updatecoords.php?x=" + coord3.left + "&y=" + coord3.top + "&id=" + pos3 + "";
                   $('#result3').load(url3, function() {
                   });
                   var coord4 = $('#4').position();
                   var url4 = "updatecoords.php?x=" + coord4.left + "&y=" + coord4.top + "&id=" + pos4 + "";
                   $('#result4').load(url4, function() {
                   });
                   var coord5 = $('#5').position();
                   var url5 = "updatecoords.php?x=" + coord5.left + "&y=" + coord5.top + "&id=" + pos5 + "";
                   $('#result5').load(url5, function() {
                   });
                   var coord6 = $('#6').position();
                   var url6 = "updatecoords.php?x=" + coord6.left + "&y=" + coord6.top + "&id=" + pos6 + "";
                   $('#result6').load(url6, function() {
                   });
    });

});
</script>
```

I use the jquery library multidraggable which works great. I understand my problem is with how I've organized the code but I cannot figure out how I should do it.

Thank you in advance!
Emil

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a small plugin named inettuts.You can drag,sort and store their order using this ..

You wil get required info from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514660/how-to-create-draggable-widgets/7514742#7514742) answer

Comment: I can already store their position. My problem is with trying to select multiple divs and store their positions at once. With the code I have written I must select them in the order they appear in the code to be able to store their positions.