# laravel user editable layout - is it possible?

Tags: user-interface, laravel-5, layout

I'm trying to build a view in laravel that will allow the user to drag and drop widget on and off the page as well as around the page and resizing them.

Everything I read suggests this is not possible in laravel as the view seems fairly immutable.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

ok.. no laravel can't do it, at least thats what I think..

However you can do it with javascript and store the widget locations in laravel..

Things I did find though for the next person...

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514660/how-to-create-draggable-widgets
 https://github.com/hootsuite/grid
 https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-mimic-the-igoogle-interface--net-1794
```

Comment: just for others... gridstack is working for me. using view and js